# How does this program snippet check whether an object declared is in the current scope of the javascript program

Tags: javascript, scope

```
  for(var scope = env; scope; scope = Object.getPrototypeOf(scope)){
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(scope, name)){
      scope[name] = value;
      return value;
    }
    throw new ReferenceError("Setting undefined object " + name);
  }
```

The `env` object is the global scope object in the program. `name` is the object which I'm using to find whether it is declared previously or not and `value` is the value of the `name` object that is assigned to it when it is found to be declared in the scope. Else it throws an error. Can I get an explanation of what is going on in the for loop?

Comment: It walks the prototype chain. Where did you get that snippet from? Please cite the source and attribute the author.

Comment: @Bergi I'm reading the book Eloquent Javascript which is written by Marijn Haverbeke.

Comment: Which chapter specifically? We might be able to give you a bit more context then.

Comment: @Bergi [link](http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_language.html#h_Y9ZDMshYCQ)

Comment: Ah, yes (I was looking through the first version). No, `env` is *not* the global scope, it's the local scope. And the loop iterates the scope chain until there is no more `scope` (i.e. `scope == null`).

Comment: yes Thank you @Bergi I understood where the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `scope` refers to a particular object in env's prototype chain.

The for loop works its way up the prototype chain to determine the actual object where the property is set so that it can replace it there (rather than override it lower in the chain).

If it can't find any object in the prototype chain where the property is set, then it throws an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: `When trying to access a property of an object, the property will not only be sought on the object but on the prototype of the object, the prototype of the prototype, and so on until either a property with a matching name is found or the end of the prototype chain is reached.`-- this solves my problem @chardy